# User's chosen alert style for an iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, settings, usernotifications

How can I know the alert style of my App, as set in the app's notification settings? That is, whether the alert style is "none" or "banners" or "alerts"? I guess there should be a property to know about it in notification center. But I did not find any.

I want to adjust the number of notifications that I post based on the style -- I believe that too many alerts will interrupt the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible. If you want to access this information, [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) about it.